# Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Feature 'GUID' is not activated at this scope

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Some strange issue is popping up while trying to deploy a solution in sharepoint.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Feature 'GUID' is not activated at this scope.

I am able to build and rebuild, but when trying to deploy, the above shown error is raised.

while trying to retract, the error raised is

> Feature 'GUID' is not activated at this scope.

It all happend suddenly.....
It was working perfectly till yesterday!!!....

How do i find out whether the feature with ID  is activated? also
How do i activate the feature?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retract and then install the solution again using 'SharePoint 2010 Management Shell' Install-SPSolution –Identity SharePointProject2.wsp –WebApplication  -GACDeployment.

Follow http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx for proper syntax. 
Once it run without error confirm that the required features are activated in the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure Features are activated. please follow
Go to  site setting.Then select manage site features in site action. Then activate that particular feature
hopes it works .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the account I was using to deploy from visual studio wasn't a site ower.  Once I added the account as site owner, It deployed fine.